# ssh-add on an intermediate ssh hop node

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I am on machine A, hopping onto machine B to finally reach machine C.

```
A --ssh--> B --ssh--> C
```

When I ssh-add my private key on A, all works fine and I can hop onto B as many times as I want without supplying any passwords.

When I ssh-add *on **B***, I get this error message:

```
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

The objective is to ssh-add on B too and from there to reach many different C's...

I know how to set up "pass-through" using .ssh/config but that's not what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `-A` option to forward the agent connection to the remote host (`ssh` commands on B will talk to the agent on A, so you don't need to ssh-add). But note that Agent forwarding may be administratively prohibited on B.

Otherwise, you'll have to start an agent on B:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent)"
ssh-add ...
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to enable authentication agent connection forwarding (Option "-A").

Example:

```
hostA$ ssh -A hostB # agent forwarding enabled
hostB$ ssh-add  
hostB$ ssh hostC   # tries now the keys from hostA and the newly added
hostC$
```

If you do not want to forward a key for security reasons,
you could start a new ssh-agent instance by using

```
hostB$ eval "$(ssh-agent)"
```