# Setup SSH tunneling to run some commands from the remote server

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

. Here's what I currently have done:

1. I have an EC2 instance (Private Instance) in a private subnet with no NAT gateway or NAT instance configured. In other words, this doesn't have any route to the outside internet except the VPC on which it resides.
2. I have a bastion host (Bastion Instance) setup in the public subnet of the same VPC on which my EC2 instance in the private subnet resides.

To be able to access the Private Instance from my local workstation, here's what I currently do:

`ssh -i identityfile -f -L 4567:172.11.11.111:22 ec2-user@50.50.50.50 “sleep 10” && ssh -i identityfile -p 4567 ec2-user@localhost`

The above command works perfectly fine for me. I'm able to connect to the **Private Instance** from my workstation without having to have my private key inside the **Bastion Instance**.

I have set of commands that I need to run on the **Private Instance**. Currently to be able to do it, I scp my private key and configuration files to the **Bastion Instance** and then run those commands from the **Bastion Instance** and they work perfectly fine.

Is there a way to run these commands from the workstation itself without having the need to copy the private keys and configuration files to the **Bastion Instance**?

Comment: You might be able to do what you want by adding your keys to your workstation's ssh agent using `ssh-add` and then forwarding the agent through your tunnel using the `-A` option ...

Comment: [This Q/A is similar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49758/ssh-add-on-an-intermediate-ssh-hop-node)